# ssl for subdirectory within nginx server configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a nginx server running with ssl enabled. 
Currently I have https enabled for all directories.
How enable ssl only for `www.example.com/shop/*` directory and disable for other??

here is my conf file :

```
    # Redirect everything to the main site.
server {
  server_name *.example.com;
  listen 80;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/conf/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/conf/server.key; 
  keepalive_timeout    70;

  access_log  /home/example/nginx_logs/access.log ;
  error_log  /home/example/nginx_logs/error.log ;

  root /home/example/public_html/example.com;   
  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;         
      root          /home/example/public_html/example.com/;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include        /opt/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
      #fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/example/public_html/example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;   
  }

    if ($http_host != "example.com") {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

    include global/restrictions.conf;

    # Additional rules go here.

    #Only include one of the files below.
    include global/wordpress.conf;
#   include global/wordpress-ms-subdir.conf;
#   include global/wordpress-ms-subdomain.conf;
}
```

tnanks,
D

Comment: No way. `ssl` is a directive that lives under `http` or `server` only (as the documentation states)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is easy to achieve in Nginx. There are two steps involved in it.

1. Port 443 will be used only when yourdomain.com/shop is accessed. All other requests would be redirected to port 80 (HTTP)
2. Port 80 will check for yourdomain.com/shop. If found, it'd be redirected to port 443 (HTTPS).

Here is a quick overview of how it could be done...

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name yourdomain.com;

  # directives for SSL certificates

  # root, index, error_log, access_log directives

  location /shop {
    # directives to handle what's inside /shop, for example
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # directives to handle PHP files
  }

  # leave everything else to port 80
  location / {
    rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name yourdomain.com;

  # root, index, error_log, access_log directives

  # redirect yourdomain.com/shop to port 443
  # Please put this before location / block as
  # nginx stops after seeing the first match
  location /shop {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location / {
    # directives to handle what's inside /, for example
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # directives to handle PHP files
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo and option naming, @atmosx .